# How to become a good developer in Salesforce

Tags: learning

**Experience is a great teacher.** 
I have been working on Salesforce since 2014 and worked on different basic projects. I have developed Apex classes, Visualforce Pages and worked on admin part of the Salesforce.

My Question is whatever i learned in Salesforce from Job experience but Salesforce is not limited to apex classes, VF pages, there are other things to learn in salesforce like interigation, Webservices, Schema Classes, Rest, SOAP, Heroku etc.. So it seems if i does not get project in job profile like interigation, Webservices... then i won't be able to learn these technologies.

I have read documentation but it gives you the basic idea it does not give you real life experience of programming.

**I wanted to know what are the other way to learn coding on use cases, Real life problems, Working on projects online ?**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real experience is indeed the best way to learn. Reading documentation or going step-by-step through tutorials may not be challenging enough to really learn the most.

[Salesforce trailhead Projects](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/projects) are what you're looking for I believe.

This is a recent addition to the trailhead site and content is still being extended right now (and that won't stop). Projects **cover more functionality** and are **intended to mimic (downsized) real life projects** for which you'll need to execute multiple different steps , needing different skills and knowledge, to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Now there are many good resources to learn, starting with Salesforce Quick workbooks would be good. The developer guides be it VF Page developer guide or others would be needed throughout your salesforce developer career as a reference. We need to understand that Apex, VF etc is platform dependent language so a good understanding of platform is must to become a good developer . Now you cannot get real experience without job and you cannot get a job without a bit of atleast theoretical knowledge.
I know there are lot of you tube videos, and people also find the documentation boring. So there are ways wherein you can look for sites like Intellipaat.com, Pluralsight.com etc where some good salesforce personalities have shared their video courses. 
I download the courses in usb drive and plug it into my large screen TV and sit and watch . Just repeat the video 2 - 3 times and it will stick to your mind.
I started learning salesforce approx an year ago and the best and structured training I have found till date is
http://courses.getskillsfast.com/

Even if you do not want to go for it then check some courses on pluralsight, I have taken many courses but why I recommended this training is because it does not contain the boring PPTs like others and most other courses are very high level and do not go deep, while this one is all hands on and to the point so keeps you engaged.